# How to setAliasTexParameters of CCNode<CCRGBAProtocol>?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have successfully implemented slider to my Cocos2D project using [this resource](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/tips%3aslider_widget).

The problem is that I make my game using pixel art so I usually use `[sprite.texture setAliasTexParameters];` to make them look crisp. I just can't figure out how to do it with this example code.

[This](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/279125/Kuvankaappaus%202012-3-24%20kello%201.02.13.png) is what the slider looks like now.

I create the slider like this:

```
self.musicSlider = [CCMenuItemSlider itemFromTrackImage: @"slider_bar.png" knobImage: @"slider_knob.png" target:self selector: @selector(onMusicSlide:)];
```

I believe here's all the code you need to see from the mentioned example .m file:

```
+(id) itemFromTrackImage: (NSString*)value knobImage:(NSString*) value2 {
return [[[self alloc] initFromTrackImage:value knobImage:value2 target:nil selector:nil] autorelease];
}

+(id) itemFromTrackImage: (NSString*)value knobImage:(NSString*) value2 target:(id) t selector:(SEL) s {
return [[[self alloc] initFromTrackImage:value knobImage:value2 target: t selector: s] autorelease];
}

-(id) initFromTrackImage: (NSString *)trkImage
           knobImage: (NSString *)knbImage
              target: (id)target
            selector: (SEL)selector
{
if( (self=[super initWithTarget:target selector:selector]) ) {
    self.trackImage     = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: trkImage];
    self.knobImage      = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: knbImage];

    // Content size of the track is our reference
    // Knob must lie within
    [self setContentSize: trackImage_.contentSize];
    [self addChild: knobImage_ z:2];

    isVertical  = (self.contentSize.height > self.contentSize.width);
    self.minValue   = 0.0f;
    self.maxValue   = 100.0f;
    self.value  = 50.0f;
    }
return self;
}
```

The sprite is declared `CCNode<CCRGBAProtocol>` in the .h file and I can't put `.texture` behind that.

Thank you very much in advance for all the help and please ask, if you need some more specifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by changing the code so it uses sprite sheet and not single images.

I changed this:

```
self.trackImage     = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: trkImage];
```

To this:

```
self.trackImage     = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName: trkImage];
```

I thought I tried this yesterday before asking, but I guess I was too tired and did some stupid mistake.